# Comparing $\frac{(x+n)!}{x!}$ to $n!$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, inequality, prime-numbers, factorial

- Let $n \ge 2$ be an integer and $p$ be a prime that divides $n!$.
- Let $x \ge n$ be an integer.
- Let $v_p(u)$ be the highest power of $p$ that divides $u$.

It is well known that $n!$ divides $\dfrac{(x+n)!}{x!}$.

Let $x+j$ be the integer in the sequence $\{x+1, x+2, \dots, x+n\}$ divisible by the highest power of $p$.

Does it follow that $v_p(x+j) \ge v_p({{x+n}\choose{n}})$?

I am thinking that the answer is yes.

Here's my thinking:

(1)  Let $p^t$ be the highest power of $p$ in the sequence ${x+1, x+2, \dots, x+n}$.

(2)  Using [Legendre's Formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legendre%27s_formula), it is well known that $p^{v_p({{x+n}\choose{n}})} \le x+n$  [See see this [paper](https://users.renyi.hu/~p_erdos/1934-01.pdf) for the argument].

(3)  So, $v_p({{x+n} \choose {x}}) \le t$ and $p^{v_p\left({{x+n} \choose {x}}\right)}$ necessarily divides $x+j$.

---

Edit:  Cleaning up the question.  I think that much of my original assumptions are unnecessary.

---

Edit 2:  @Mathlove points out a mistake in my reasoning.  For $x=5, n=4, p=2$ for example, $v_p\left({{x+n}\choose{x}}\right) < t$

This is consistent with my conclusion even if it changes the details of my argument.

This question relates to step(6) in a [previous question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2905753/48606).

Comment: In (3), $v_p({{x+n} \choose {x}}) = t$ is not always true. Take $x=5,n=4,p=2$. (You might want to write in the question about the fact that this question is related with [your previous question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2905753/question-about-least-common-multiples-of-a-sequence-of-consecutive-integers).

Comment: Thanks very much.  This suggests that $v_p \le t$ instead of $v_p = t$.  I have updated my question.  As I understand it, this leads to the same conclusion, an answer of yes to my question.